# Problema con SQLite en Android

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo android y me estoy rompiendo la cabeza con un problema. Hice una app para cargar productos en una SQLite y todo va bien con la carga, pero al momento de querer levantar los datos y mandarlos con putExtra se sale la aplicacion del emulador y el problema me lo marca en el rawQuery.

este es mi codigo

```
public void consCod(View v){
    
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Consulta.class);

    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "Administración",null,1);

    SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();

    String cod = etCodigo.getText().toString();

    Cursor fila = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT Proveedor,Descripcion,Valor,Cantidad FROM Articulos WHERE Codigo= " +cod,null);
    if (fila.moveToFirst()){
        intent.putExtra(mensExtra1, cod);
        intent.putExtra(mensExtra2, fila.getString(0));
        intent.putExtra(mensExtra3,fila.getString(1));
        intent.putExtra(mensExtra4, fila.getString(2));
        intent.putExtra(mensExtra5, fila.getString(3));
        startActivity(intent);
    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No existe ese codigo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido, super importante revisar el LogCat, de otra forma pueden ser muchas las causas,¿algún mensaje de error?, saludos.

Comment: Jorgesys... Si.. Eso lo tuve en cuenta.. Pero en Pestaña de RUN me marcaba el problema en el rawQerry por que dice que no enuentra la tabla, pero el nombre en la peticion esta igual